# Converting NumPy array to Pandas without dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For some weird reason, my professor wants us to convert a given Numpy array to a Pandas without using the dataframe method. Any suggestions for how I should tackle this? don't really know where to start. Thank you.

Question:

Pandas provide various methods that can be used to handle data more efficiently. So we will convert our NumPy data into Pandas dataframe type. Write a function convert_to_df(data) that uses the data's dtype names as column headers and their associated data values.

You cannot use the pd.DataFrame() function for this task

Comment: Convert each column of your numpy array into a `Series` then use `pd.concat` to create the dataframe? Or dump your numpy array into a csvfile then load it with `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` is a class, not a function. So, the question could be read as "create a DataFrame object without explicitly declaring it". Corralien's suggestions work, but those functions are actually calling themselves the class in their own code. So, you would be using `pd.DataFrame()`, but wouldn't be aware because somebody else wrote those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've omitted a lot information, or confused the terminology.

- `dataframe method` - there is a `pd.DataFrame` class; that's not a `method`.
- What is `our NumPy data`?  I'm tempted to close this question for lack of information.

However, the phrase `data's dtype names` suggests that your `data` is a structured array, with a compound dtype and field names.

So a wild guess is that you have an array like:

```
In [117]: data = np.ones(3, 'i,f,U10')

In [118]: data
Out[118]: 
array([(1, 1., '1'), (1, 1., '1'), (1, 1., '1')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10')])
```

There is a `DataFrame` class method that can make a frame from such an array:

```
In [119]: df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)

In [120]: df
Out[120]: 
   f0   f1 f2
0   1  1.0  1
1   1  1.0  1
2   1  1.0  1
```

However using the class definition approach (which supposedly you aren't supposed to use), we get the same thing:

```
In [121]: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[121]: 
   f0   f1 f2
0   1  1.0  1
1   1  1.0  1
2   1  1.0  1
```

We don't know what you've been learning.  Good homework questions build on stuff that's allready been taught.  I don't know how much of this confusion and lack of information is the instructor's, and how much is yours.